# How can I retrieve data in Power Apps from a SharePoint list based on source list item ID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, powerapps-forms, id

What I want to do is have fields like FormID1, FormID2, FormID3, etc. in my Power App solution, and be able to retrieve combinations of item detail from any connected lists on load, using source list ID numbers provided by Power Automate.

This can be used to compose a logical aggregate of relevant information in my Power App.

The idea is to be able to deploy quickly in PoC solutions, when it matters instead of some convoluted ordeal for every field that I need to retrieve.

How can I do this with Power Apps?

What is the best way to do this in Power Apps?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerApps, you can add SharePoint list as data source to get detailed information of the items in that list. A simple doc about it:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-data-connection

For searching list items with ID, here is a thread may help you about it:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-PowerApps-search-the-Default-ID-field-in-SharePoint/td-p/124659